# HtmlUnit ignore configuration and throws exception

Tags: java, htmlunit, remote-server

HtmlUnit still throws exceptions based on JS errors. I've tried

```
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

but still return

```
ERROR c.g.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage - Error loading JavaScript from [http://example.com/mobilenew/js/jquery.mobile.swipe.min.js].
java.io.IOException: Unable to download JavaScript from 'http://example.com/mobilenew/js/jquery.mobile.swipe.min.js' (status 404).
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadJavaScriptFromUrl(HtmlPage.java:1082) ~[htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1009) ~[htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.executeScriptIfNeeded(HtmlScript.java:395) [htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript$3.execute(HtmlScript.java:276) [htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript.onAllChildrenAddedToPage(HtmlScript.java:290) [htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:800) [htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:na]
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HTMLParser$HtmlUnitDOMBuilder.endElement(HTMLParser.java:757) [htmlunit-2.18.jar:2.18]
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.callEndElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1170) [nekohtml-1.9.22.jar:1.9.22]
        at org.cyberneko.html.HTMLTagBalancer.endElement(HTMLTagBalancer.java:1072) [nekohtml-1.9.22.jar:1.9.22]
```

This error appears only on remote server. At local machine , running spock test , htmlUnit works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using these below

```
        LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.StrictErrorReporter").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.ActiveXObject").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.html.HTMLDocument").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlScript").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.WindowProxy").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.OFF);
```